# Word meaning "not able to be cheated"

Tags: single-word-requests, american-english

If something can be cheated, then word means something which cannot be cheated? The sample sentence I'm trying to write is:

> With his extensive background in statistical theory, he was able to create a <*word here*> scoring system.

Comment: This word may be slightly different in meaning, but "impregnable" is an option: (of a fortified position) unable to be captured or broken into.; unable to be defeated or destroyed; unassailable.

Comment: There is, in fact, the word [_uncheatable_](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/uncheatable) in Wiktionary.

Comment: @alwayslearning - [Merriam-Webster doesn't list it](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/uncheatable), and neither does the [Oxford English dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&filter=dictionary&query=uncheatable). I think someone made that up.

Comment: @eykanal, that's precisely why I did not bother to add it as an answer. However, I don't think we can discount the Wiktionary definition completely since it does include a couple of _quotations_ (usage examples) using the word.

Comment: Why not make such up? How could "uncheatable" be wrong while we use "unbeatable" or "uneatable"and possibly even "unseatable"

Otherwise yes, Edwin's "foolproof" seems… uh… foolproof…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose *reliable* is not absolute enough. And *unassailable* doesn't really work. However,

> **foolproof**
>
> ADJECTIVE
>
> Incapable of going wrong or being misused:
>
> ‘a foolproof security system’ [[ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/foolproof)]

is usable here.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest [incorruptable](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/incorruptible)

> incapable of corruption: as
>
> - not subject to decay or dissolution
> - incapable of being bribed or morally corrupted

It encapsulates two ideas - the thing won't break down of its own accord, and people will not be able to break it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare his background to a mountain over which no cheater could possibly pass, you could call it **insurrmountable**.  OED defines it as "That cannot be surmounted, overcome, or passed over" (www.oed.com, 2016).